# EDit Django admin Form so that only staff users can change users password

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have django project in which I modified Django admin form for editing users , here i have made Password a ReadOnly Field . Thus no one can change user password . But I wants that Staff user can change password . So for that I want to provide a link to Staff users and from that link Staff user can change password of user .

I was wondering if this is possible from  Django form (the same model from where I have made the password field readonly) .

My admin form code :

```
class CustomUserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the below code in your form

```
password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField(label= ("Password"),
        help_text= ("Raw passwords are not stored, so there is no way to see "
                    "this user's password, but you can change the password "
                    "using <a href=\"password/\">this form</a>."))
```

as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456964/changing-password-in-django-admin)