# Where to inherit and override UserChangeForm if I want to enable password modification in the Django Admin area?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15630360/5836391), if I want to enable the ability to change user passwords in the admin area, I need to add/change some code in UserChangeForm.

I understand this does not mean change the original UserChangeForm, but rather, I should inherit the class which contains the UserChangeForm method, and override the method.

I don't understand where I am supposed to do this. Could someone please give me an example of where/how to override UserChangeForm? Assume I am using a custom user model which inherits AbstractBaseUser.

This is the code (from the linked answer above) for modifying passwords which should go in UserChangeForm:

```
password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField(label= ("Password"),
        help_text= ("Raw passwords are not stored, so there is no way to see "
                    "this user's password, but you can change the password "
                    "using <a href=\"password/\">this form</a>."))
```

Note I am assuming this will actually display the correct form which will correctly change the password, but it's possible I'm being naive about that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add your own users app and inherit from django auth user. see my code:
This should be your models.py, no need to change any form for this task

```
  from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  class UserProfile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User)
        # other fields  
        email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=False, null=False,
            unique=True)
        weight = models.IntegerField(default=0,
            validators=[
                MaxValueValidator(9),
                MinValueValidator(0)
            ])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm a little confused about it though. This will turn on the ability to change passwords in the admin area for my custom user model?

Comment: I tried using your code with my user model and it doesn't do anything. Thanks for trying anyway.