# Django: admin interface: how to change user password

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In Django:

I have created a super user and can view all the users

I have also implemented forgot password for my user, who can input their email and a password reset link is sent to their email and then the user can reset his password

But how can admin change some users password from the admin dashboard

Comment: Changing password in admin seems not secure. Is there any specific reason why you want to do that?

Comment: In case you customized the UserChangeForm, the answer is here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456964/changing-password-in-django-admin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer is just an extension of answer by @kunal Sharma

To change user password from Django admin

Go into the user

[image]

and click this form, and a form below will be shown, change password there

[image]

Answer (score 18):

Django does not store raw (clear text) passwords on the user model, but only a hash (see the [documentation of how passwords are managed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/passwords/) for full details). Because of this, do not attempt to manipulate the password attribute of the user directly. This is why a helper function is used when creating a user.

**To change a user’s password, you have several options:**

`manage.py changepassword *username*` offers a method of changing a user’s password from the command line. It prompts you to change the password of a given user which you must enter twice. If they both match, the new password will be changed immediately. If you do not supply a user, the command will attempt to change the password whose username matches the current system user.

You can also change a password programmatically, using [set_password()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
u = User.objects.get(username='john')
u.set_password('new password')
u.save()
```

If you have the Django admin installed, you can also change user’s passwords on the [authentication system’s admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#auth-admin) pages.
Django also provides views and forms that may be used to allow users to change their own passwords.

Changing a user’s password will log out all their sessions. [See Session invalidation on password change](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#session-invalidation-on-password-change) for details.

Answer (score 14):

We can reset other user password from Django admin interface by adding `UserAdmin` in `admin.py` file. Used Django 3.1 for the example.

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Then we will able to see the below section in the user edit page of Django admin interface.

[image]

By clicking on the `this form` we can go to the reset password form.

[image]

Comment: This is a perfect solution.

Answer (score 8):

In your admin.py file, you can register a `UserAdmin` to your `User` model like so:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as DjangoUserAdmin
from django.contrib import admin
from <my-app> import models    

@admin.register(models.User)
class UserAdmin(DjangoUserAdmin):
    
    # extra logic:
    ...
```

Answer (score -2):

Run these commands in your CMD and then set change any user password:

```
python manage.py shell
from django.contrib.auth.models import
u=User.objects.get(username="user.name")
u
u.set_password("mynewpasssword")
u.save
```

Comment: I think it should be u.save()

Comment: The second line should be ```from django.contrib.auth.models import User``