# How do I enable Django 5 admin area to change users password? It currently shows a hashed password value and plain text entry doesn't allow login

Tags: django-models

I've inherited the base AbtractUser model and created a custom user model. I have not touched the password field. In the admin area it shows a hashed password. I've tried to enter a password into this field and save the form but the user is unable to login and the password doesn't become hashed. How do I deal with this in django 5 so that admins can change users passwords? Below is my current custom user model ->

```
class MyCustomUser(AbstractUser):
    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        ('APPLICANT', 'Applicant'),
        ('EMPLOYEE', 'Employee'),
        ('ADMIN', 'Admin'),
        (None, 'None')
    )
    role = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=ROLE_CHOICES, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    profile_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/', blank=True, null=True)  # Specify upload directory and make it optional if you want
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'UserAdmin' model included with Django to implement this. Inherit UserAdmin in your custom user administration class. Fields in my custom user model disappeared. I had to include those fields in fieldsets after creating a custom form. Solution below:

*admin.py*

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import MyCustomUser
from .forms import MyCustomUserForm
class MyCustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = MyCustomUser
    add_form = MyCustomUserForm
    fieldsets = (
        *UserAdmin.fieldsets,
        (
            'Role',
            {
                'fields': (
                    'role',
                )
            }   
        )
    )
    list_filter = ('role',)
admin.site.register(MyCustomUser, MyCustomUserAdmin)
```

*forms.py*

```
from django_registration.forms import RegistrationForm
from authentication.models import MyCustomUser
class MyCustomUserForm(RegistrationForm): 
    class Meta(RegistrationForm.Meta):
        model = MyCustomUser
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'profile_photo', 'role']
```

*models.py*

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class MyCustomUser(AbstractUser):
    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        ('APPLICANT', 'Applicant'),
        ('EMPLOYEE', 'Employee'),
        ('ADMIN', 'Admin'),
        (None, 'None')
    )
    role = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=ROLE_CHOICES, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    profile_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/', blank=True, null=True) 
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

I learned this from these two posts:

[Django: admin interface: how to change user password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65240677/django-admin-interface-how-to-change-user-password)

[Custom User model fields (AbstractUser) not showing in django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48011275/custom-user-model-fields-abstractuser-not-showing-in-django-admin)