# My Custom AuthBackend does not work with Admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-authentication

I have written a custom authentication middleware, that authenticates users based on email field and not username, but now I am unable to log into the Admin Panel of Django, using email of the Superuser/staff:

```
def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
    # Passing email as username
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(email=username)
        if user.check_password(password):
            return user
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return None

 def get_user(self, user_id):
   # Get User Object from user_id
    try:
        return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

It would be great if someone could help me through this?

Comment: You need to post the code you wrote, how you implemented it, and any error you got. Otherwise I am not sure what kind of help can anyone give.

Comment: 'code' def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        # Passing email as username
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=username) 'code'
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

Comment: Django does not spit out any errors for the same

Comment: Please see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13661977/1474569

Comment: I updated your question with your code. What happens if the password isn't correct?

Comment: @ Andrey I have not defined a custom user model, I am just authenticating the user using email rather than username.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid : it does not return anything when the password/username is incorrect.

Comment: Where is the rest of the authentication backend? Does it have a `get_user()` method?

Comment: @Bibhas : Yes, the Auth Backend has the get_user() method as mentioned in the question

Comment: Your code seems correct. There might be other things wrong, things we can't get from this code. E.g. - 1. These methods are inside a backend class, right? 2. It's added correctly as auth backend in `settings.py` under `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`, 3. The given credentials are indeed superuser credentials, 4. the user account is active etc. Make sure these things are in place. It's hard to debug without any error message. You could also try using `pdb` inside the auth backend to be sure that it's working perfectly.

Comment: I have cross verified all the above, and as I said Django does not spit of any error.